# Redirect to page with different page layout in React

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to redirect after successful login to a page that has a different CSS layout. For example, I have a corporate page with the typical navbar like Home, About Us, Services, and Login. And after successful login, it supposes to redirect to like Admin Bootstrap Dashboard page. But I keep getting the corporate page navbar but the url clearly shows localhost:3000/dashboard. Where did I go wrong? Thanks here is the code:

```
App.js

 <Switch>
      <Fragment>   
      <Helmet>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
        <meta content="" name="keywords"/>
        <meta content="" name="description"/>  
      </Helmet>   
          <Header/> 
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
          <Route exact path="/services" component={Services}/>   
      </Fragment>
 </Switch>

In the Login.js

  render() {
        if(this.state.isAuthenticated){
            return(<Redirect to={'/Dashboard'}/>)
        }


In the Dashboard.js


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad idea to store the state variable like isUserAuthenticated inside the protected Route which is the Dashboard in your case. Let me explain what the above code does, It first renders the dashboard component then after the first mount of dashboard the code decides whether the user is authenticated or not and conditionally redirects. And also to mention the variable unauthenticated is a component-level state which means there is no way for other components to know if user is authenticated or not.

Now where it could go wrong, you might need the auth state of the user in the header component where you would render a logout button if the user is authenticated or a login button. Some other component might also need the auth state of the user.

So the best approach would be to use better state management like context API or redux if you are comfortable with it.

Whether to use redux or not is whole another discussion. So here is a simple solution using context API to solve the problem.

in AuthContext.js

```
const AuthContext = React.CreateContext(null)


const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false)

    const login = () => {
        // your authentication logic
        setIsAuthenticated(true)
    }

    const logout = () => {
        // your logout logic
        setIsAuthenticated(false)
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{isAuthenticated, login, logout}}>
           {props.children}
        <AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

In App.js wrap your app with the AuthContextProvider

```
function App(props) {
    return (
        <AuthContextProvider>
            // all other app logic
            // like <Switch>
            //          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            //      <Switch/>
        <AuthContextProvider>
    )
}
```

now to make the dashboard route protected you can take this approach make a new private route component

in PrivateRoute.js

```
 function PrivateRoute(props) {
    // keep in mind path is required as a prop
    const { path, children, ...rest } = props;

    // using the AuthContext to get the state variable isAuthenticated
    const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);


    return (
        <Route
        exact
        path={path}
        render={({ location }) =>
            isAuthenticated ? (
            children
            ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: location } }} />
            )
        }
        />
    );
}
```

when rendering the protected pages like the dashboard in your case render the route like this inside the Switch, same goes for any other private routes

```
<Switch>
    // other routes
    // for example <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>

    // The Dashboard route
    <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard">
        <Dashboard/>
    <PrivateRoute/>

<Switch/>
```

Keep in mind that the login and logout function comes from the context so any component using the login or logout functions needs to use the AuthContext as well. And also you could implement the same logic with redux if your app is already using it or if you are more comfortable with redux.

This is a lot harder to implement in code so let me know if you could implement it in your app.

Here are some links to the documentation if you need to reference it.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: Thanks, Subash. There are still a  lot more things to learn about react. I will look into context instead. For now, I will just do some research on how to use Context API in a simple way and hopefully get used to it. It is too overwhelming now. Thanks, again

Comment: Context API can be challenging for the first time.

Comment: Another simple solution would be to convert the App component to a class component. If you comfortable using class components let me know I can provide some code snippets for your use case.

Comment: Thanks Subash. In the beginning, I used class component and then I read about useState and useEffect and it says it is a preferred way of doing things. And many articles I read say that as much as possible go for functional components. The project I am doing now is a mix of class components when I begin this project and as I continue this along, I begin to use functional components. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be instead of rendering all the meta tags, title, and other layout related code inside the switch, create a new layout component that wraps another component like Home or About.

example

```
function Layout(props) {
    return (
     <Fragment>
       <Helmet>
          <title>{props.title}</title>
          <meta content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0" 
          name="viewport"/>
          <meta content="" name="keywords"/>
          <meta content="" name="description"/>  
       </Helmet>
       <Header/>
       {props.children}
     <Fragment/>

    );
}

export default Layout;
```

Then in home.js use code similar to this

```
function Home(props) {
    return (
     <Layout title="My Homepage">
        // your home component
       <div>Home<div/>
     <Layout/>
   );
}

export default Home;
```

in App.js

```
function App(props) {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route exact path="/services" component={Services}/> 
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={dashboard}/>  
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

But when creating the dashboard.js you can either conditionally render the Header 
or not render the Header in Layout by modifying the layout component or create a completely different layout for the dashboard.

for example

```
function DashboardLayout(props) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
       <Helmet>
          <title>Dashboard</title>
           <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" 
            name="viewport"/>
           <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
        <Helmet>
          {props.children}
    </Fragment>
    );
}

funcition Dashboard(props) {
    return (
        <DashboardLayout>
            // your dashboard component
            <div>Dashboard</div>
        <DashboardLayout>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

I think what you are trying to do is to render the whole app with a global layout, but you want the dashboard to be different. In that case above solution works but if you are trying to share some component with all the routes even with the dashboard, and exclude some component from one route like dashboard try this approach.

```
    function App(props) {
    return (
       <Fragment>
            // Your global components which will be shared
            // with all your routes e.g. Header, Footer

            <Header/>
            <SomeOtherGlobalComponent/>

            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <Route exact path="/services" component={Services}/>
                <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={dashboard}/>
            </Switch>
            <Footer/>
        <Fragment>
    )
}
```

Let me know if the solution helps.