# Using different page template for React Login/Register page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I use an Admin Dashboard in my React app and now I will add a Login and Register pages to the app. However, I am not sure how can I make login and register routes to use a different template than the app. I trşed something below, but it is too ugly and I think there would be a better way in React.

**Note:** I thought to check if the user logged in or not in App.js or index.js and then use the necessary component e.g. navbar.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        {localStorage.getItem("currentUser") != null ? <AppBar></AppBar> : null}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/create" component={Form} />

          // ...
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The second issue is, should I use an `AuthContextProvider` to check if the user authenticated or not instead of `localStorage.getItem("currentUser") != null` as metioned on the following approach? Any idea?

[Redirect to page with different page layout in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61892504/redirect-to-page-with-different-page-layout-in-react)

Comment: Regarding your second issue : We use Context Providers to globally access the variable in the whole app. While local storage do allow allow us to globally access values in the whole app as well as it does not loose its value on component render. So you should saves user information in localstorage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. Of course I will use `localstorage`, but I am just wondering if should I use `AuthContextProvider` to show / hide different page templates. Any idea?

Comment: As per case of ContextProvider, if your user reload the page or comes back to check your webapp, your templates may messed up with this situation.  So just use localstorage or ContextProvider based upon your situation.

Comment: Considering your present situation, I would suggest do not go for authContextProvider.

Comment: So that it may make something more complex, right? Then, I think I should go via your suggestion, right?

Comment: @fredrick I'm not a moderator, but I can see two deleted answers here. By a quick look at them, I'm pretty sure they were written using ChatGPT which is not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I do not think so, because I checked the profiles and they seem to be experienced developers. On the other hand, I am so surprised to know that people use it. It is too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution might help you :

**Index.js**

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
<Switch>
        {localStorage.getItem("currentUser") != null ? <AppBar /> : null}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/create" component={<Form />} />
         <Route exact path="/register" component={<Register />} /> //register component
         <Route exact path="/login" component={<Login />} /> //login component
</Switch>
    </div>
```

);
}

Comment: Sounds good and cleaner explanations, thanks a lot and voted+. Actually, this also seems a cleaner solution and I am confused which one is better. Could you pls compare this approach with the second approach that @Iva suggested?

Comment: Since we both are using the same approach, but hers is even better than me. you should go for it. Happy Day!

Comment: Do I need to `StrictMode` for this approach? And in this approach, do I have to set all the routes (I think it is not possible to define a default component so that the routes for which a component is not set would use that component). ?

Comment: Since StrictMode highlights issues or errors in program, so you always need it. You have to set routes for every component. also there is no default component , you may use a default path or starting path that would be '/'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not sure how to properly check if the user is authenticated and then let the request access or forward the request to login page without using `AuthContext` for this example. Any idea?